# android gridview with adapter class from data from webservice

Tags: android, arrays, web-services, gridview, adapter

This is my gridview.java class

```
public class TextGridActivity extends Activity {

String[] _cataId=new String[100] ;
String[] _cataName=new String[100];
  String[] _cataDes=new String[100];
  String[] _cataCode=new String[100];
      int num,k=0;
         int len=10;
      String[] temp ;
DataAdapter mAdapter;

GridView gridView;
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetItemCategory";

 private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

     String METHOD_NAME = "GetItemCategory";



 String res="";
  private static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:63395/Service1.asmx";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

fillTitle();

    createViews();
}

    public void createViews()
      { 

         mAdapter = new DataAdapter(this,_cataId,_cataName,_cataDes,_cataCode,len);
      GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);  

    gridview.setAdapter(mAdapter);}
//method for soap call
       public void fillTitle(){
       SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {

     androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
     KvmSerializable response = (KvmSerializable)envelope.bodyIn;

    res= response.getProperty(0).toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, res,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String delimiter = ";";
      temp= res.split(delimiter);


    for(int i=0;i<len; i++)
    {
        _cataId[i]=temp[i].substring(29);
    //Toast.makeText(this, _cataId[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _cataName[i]=temp[i+1].substring(9);
        //Toast.makeText(this, _cataName[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _cataDes[i]=temp[i+2].substring(9);
        //Toast.makeText(this, _cataDes[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        _cataCode[i]=temp[i+3].substring(10);
        //Toast.makeText(this, _cataCode[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     i=i+4;



    }


} 
    catch (Exception e) {

    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } }
    }
```

this is my DataAdapter.java class

```
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{                  
       Context mContext;

      private String[] _cataId ;
     private  String[] _cataName;
      private String[] _cataDes;
      private String[] _cataCode;
       int len;

     public DataAdapter(Context mContext, String [] cataId, String [] cataName, String[] cataDes, String[] cataCode,int len) {

         super();
          this.mContext=mContext;
         this._cataId=cataId;
         this._cataName = cataName;
         this._cataDes = cataDes;
         this._cataCode = cataCode;
           this.len = len;
         }

       private LayoutInflater mInflater;
       public DataAdapter(Context c)
       {
              mContext=c;
              mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
       }
       public int getCount()
       {
              return len;
       }


       public Object getItem(int position)
       {


           return  position;

       }


    public long getItemId(int position)
       {
              return position;
       }


       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
       {
              ViewHolder holder=null;
              if(convertView==null)
              {
                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid, null);
                     holder = new ViewHolder();
                     holder.txtId=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
                    // holder.txtId.setPadding(30, 10,10 , 10);
                     holder.txtName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                    //holder.txtName.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);
                     holder.txtDes=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDes);
                   // holder.txtDes.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);
                     holder.txtCode=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCode);
                   // holder.txtCode.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);
                     if(position==0)
                     {                             
                           convertView.setTag(holder);
                     }
              }
              else
              {
                     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
              }
              holder.txtId.setText(_cataId[position]);
              holder.txtName.setText(_cataName[position]);
              holder.txtDes.setText(_cataDes[position]);
              holder.txtCode.setText(_cataCode[position]);

              return convertView;
       }
       static class ViewHolder
       {        

            TextView txtId;        
              TextView txtName; 
              TextView txtDes;
            TextView txtCode;
       }
}
```

the data is coming in the res variable.and it is delimited by (;)  . i have toasted all the data and its going in ,_cataId,_cataName,_cataDes,_cataCode and is toasted to ensure its coming or not.

now my problem is im geeting force close on CreateViews() method.. in that madapter used n grid is clledd. plz tell me what im doing wrong while calling this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get [ANR](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) since the communication is on the UI thread. as of android 4 .

for all long (or unknown time) operations , use them on a thread that is not the UI thread , and update the UI thread only when needed.

read this for more info:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

in order to avoid it ,you can use strict mode:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Comment: ts not realed to ANR. further the error is in the CREATEVIEWS() methods .......as when ever i call this method it hapens..otherwise i can toast the data successfully but unable to embed the data in the gridview.....plz respond its urgent

Comment: which android version do you have ? i think that on the new versions , communication is not even allowed via the UI thread. also , in the CreateViews() , you have a function called "fillTitle" , which seems to be the one that does the communication ,and it is in the UI thread. am i right?

Comment: i have done web communication in ui threads in various other modules of the same code they all are working fine

Comment: thses are two seperate function filltitle n createviews and the are being called in onCreate

Comment: can u chk my adapter call if im doing something wrong with mAdapter

Comment: just that you've done it doesn't mean that it's a good thing to do . anyway, please show the log of the exception that you get . if it's really a crash and not ANR , we should be able to see some clues in the log.

Comment: about the adapter , why did you set the viewHolder only for position 0? it doesn't make sense . please see this video for why there is a viewHolder : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: btw, here is an exception about network being used on the ui thread: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html . on honeycomb and above, it will occur .

Comment: can u tell me how to set  viewHolder for more than one position

Comment: did you check the video i've written about ? the viewHolder is meant to be per view of the adapter . simply remove the check of the position . it makes no sense to use it for just a single view , since this way only this view's children will be updated (and usually with the wrong content).

Comment: sobia says thanku somuch...will check the video......n have removed the chk but its still not working

Comment: you didn't update the code in the post , and you didn't put the log of the exception . also , i would suggest making a minimal project and code that shows the problem instead of such a large code , since it's harder to read it this way .

Comment: ok , i've made a sample project out of your code . found some problems: mInflater isn't initialized (you use the longer CTOR which doesn't initialize it) , so you get null pointer exception . about the for-loop , you increase the 'i' variable twice : one by 1 (using ++) and another by 4 . i think you want to only increase it by 4 . i would suggest to never create a complex code on the first run and instead build your code in many small steps so that it will be easier to find your bugs.

Comment: anyway , for next time , please check the logs , try to debug , try to create a small sample project to see what's wrong , and then show a tiny portion of it here .

Comment: private LayoutInflater mInflater;
 is it not initalized like this?

Comment: oke now its working but the grid is not displayimg the values corectly

Comment: like in the first row only one thing is displayed n rest 3 colums are empty....i guess my loop is wrong:(

Comment: i have written that i think your for-loop is wrong . try to remove the "i++" and see if that helps. btw, your post is still not updated at all.

Comment: yes bcoz my code started working so i though y to waste ur time:P

Comment: also check your app on newer versions of android , since network operations aren't allowed to work on the UI thread anymore.